# How to do in Laravel, subquery where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've seen a lot of examples on how to do subquery with `whereIn`, but I need to do the same with `where`, like this:

```
select * from products
   where (select count(*) from items 
              where items.product_id = products.id 
              and items.exported = 0) = 0;
```

I simply tried this code:

```
Product::where(function($q) {
            $q->selectRaw('count(*)')
              ->from('items')
              ->whereRaw('items.product_id', 'products.id')
              ->where('items.exported', 0);
            }, '=', 0);
```

In this solution the result query is something like this:

```
select * from products
    where (items.product_id and exported = 0);
```

The builder loose the subquery for some reason.
How i can solve?

**SOLUTION**

```
Product::whereHas('products', function($q) {
            $q->selectRaw('count(*)')
              ->from('items')
              ->whereRaw('items.product_id', 'products.id')
              ->where('items.exported', 0);
            }, '=', 0);
```

Comment: I've just solved using whereHas instead of where. The problem is not about the query result, but the laravel sintax. Dont know if you put the -1 sign on the question, if yes you didnt understand the question

Comment: Can you post your models how they are related to each other ?

Comment: Look ad the updated question, the solution was just to use whereHas and the products relation. At the beginning i was using where, that is wrong :)